# ternary operator in ascx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this check in ListView

```
<%# Eval("Count") != null ? Eval("Count") : 0%>/<%# Eval("MaxRange")%>
```

now i want to change that if count is null then it should show nothing.

I tried this but no avail.

```
<%# Eval("Count") != null ? Eval("Count") + '/' + <%# Eval("MaxRange")%> : null %>
```

Please let me know how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: why pass a null on false part, pass an empty string instead ""

Comment: it throws this error "Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'char' There is no issue of null of empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    <%# Eval("Count") != null ? Eval("Count") + '/' +  Eval("MaxRange") : ""%>
```

I think this should work

Comment: it gives this error "Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'char'

Comment: oh sorry use <%# Eval("Count") != null ? Eval("Count") + "/" +  Eval("MaxRange") : ""%>

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%# Eval("Count") != null ? Eval("Count") + '/' + <%# Eval("MaxRange")%> : ""%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%# Eval("Count") != null ? Eval("Count") + '/' + <%# Eval("MaxRange")%> : String.Empty%>
```

Comment: Gives compilation error: Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line